# Inputs not focusable with iScroll

Tags: android, jquery, html, iscroll

I'm having troubles with cloned inputs and textareas which are not focusable. There's no JS error, and I don't really know where to search as the code is quite heavy.

```
<input name="X" type="number"/>
```

I can hack this with a little of JS:

```
$('#wrapper').on('click','input',function(){
    $(this).focus();
});
```

However, it's a poor solution as the spinner doesn't work with web browsers, and keyboard does not show up on mobile devices...

I know the question may lack some code to debug, but I just don't know what to paste. I don't see any JS event which could prevent inputs from being focusable...

Have you ever met similar behaviours? Do you have any clues?

EDIT_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**
Indeed, this is related to the use of  the iScroll script.
There are numerous posts about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because iScroll prevented the default events before scroll,just modify onBeforeScrollStart function as follow:

```
onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) { 
    var target = e.target;  
    while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;  
    if (target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA'){  
          e.preventDefault();  
    }              

}
```